# How do I use Docker's --cache-from build flag in a declarative Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, docker-build

I'm using a declarative Jenkinsfile to run some stages inside a Docker container. The process works okay but the build times are often very slow as our CI has quite a few slaves and if the build occurs on a slave without the layer cache, the entire build takes a while.

I've read that Docker can speed up builds if a `--cache-from` flag is specified. How do I specify the cache-from flag and the external registry's URL and credentials?

```
pipeline {

  agent { dockerfile true }
  environment {
    REPO = credentials('supersecret')
  }

  stages {
    stage('Prepare environment') {
      steps {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The pipeline syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) do authorize additional parameters

> You can pass additional arguments to the `docker build ...` command with the `additionalBuildArgs` option, like agent

```
{ dockerfile { additionalBuildArgs '--build-arg foo=bar' } }
```

But `cache-from` refer to an image which might be in a dedicated external registry with its own credentials.
Maybe you can setup an first step just in charge of [`docker login`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) in that registry.

---

Another approach entirely would be to reuse the same node for that specific build.
See "[Reusing node/workspace with per-stage Docker agents](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Controlling-your-build-environment#reusing-nodeworkspace-with-per-stage-docker-agents)"

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'whatever'
  }
  stages {
    stage('build') {
      steps {
        sh "./build-artifact.sh"
      }
    }
    stage('test in docker') {
      agent {
        docker {
          image 'ubuntu:16.04'
          reuseNode true
        }
      }
      steps {
        sh "./run-tests-in-docker.sh"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then any `docker build` would benefit from the current local image cache.

Comment: Indeed, using the local image cache and reusing the same node is probably the simplest solution. If you need to run the build in different nodes, though, I don't know of another solution other than pulling and using `--cache-from`, even if [there are plenty of caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56024061/149872).